# Forcing Rad GridView's pager to show

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad

[image: here the pagger should also show with 0 of 0 records displaying][image]i'm using telerik rad gridview. which is having pagging. Pagging footer shows on when record exceed the page size. i want the paging footer keep show even when no record come. the it may or should display something like that "0 of 0 records display"

i'm using mlm:Gridview which is inherited from Telerik Rad Gridview:

```
<mlm:GridView ID="mlmGridView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="mlmGridView_ItemDataBound"AutoGenerateColumns="true" ShowGroupPanel="true" SkinID="Grid" AllowSorting="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="13">
    <MasterTableView Width="100%" Summary="GridView table">              
    <NoRecordsTemplate> 
        No records to display !  
    </NoRecordsTemplate>   
    <Columns>
    </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings ReorderColumnsOnClient="True" AllowDragToGroup="True" AllowColumnsReorder="True">
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
    <Resizing AllowColumnResize="True" EnableRealTimeResize="True"></Resizing>                                
    </ClientSettings>             
    <GroupingSettings ShowUnGroupButton="true" />
</mlm:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-pageritem.html) to `true`.

```
<mlm:GridView PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="True" ...>
```